# Tesseract new font Training Failed

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using Tesseract library for an OCR project that I need to recognize a new font. I've followed this tutorial [on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpD76k2HYms), and I've added a new Font i.e. 'B Nazanin' which is popular in Farsi; but I ran into some errors presented below:

```
=== Starting training for language 'fas'
[‫شنبه ۱۶ نوامبر ۱۹، ساعت ۱۳:۳۴:۲۶ (+0330)‬] /usr/bin/text2image --fonts_dir=fonts --font=B Nazanin --outputbase=/tmp/font_tmp.0dLuk6X9KA/sample_text.txt --text=/tmp/font_tmp.0dLuk6X9KA/sample_text.txt --fontconfig_tmpdir=/tmp/font_tmp.0dLuk6X9KA
Stripped 1 unrenderable words
Error in boxaGetExtent: boxa not defined
Error in boxaAddBox: box not defined
Rendered page 0 to file /tmp/font_tmp.0dLuk6X9KA/sample_text.txt.tif
Rtl = 0 ,vertical=0

=== Phase I: Generating training images ===
Rendering using B Nazanin
[‫شنبه ۱۶ نوامبر ۱۹، ساعت ۱۳:۳۴:۲۷ (+0330)‬] /usr/bin/text2image --fontconfig_tmpdir=/tmp/font_tmp.0dLuk6X9KA --fonts_dir=fonts --strip_unrenderable_words --leading=32 --xsize=3600 --char_spacing=0.0 --exposure=0 --outputbase=/tmp/fas-2019-11-16.Upk/fas.B_Nazanin.exp0 --max_pages=10 --font=B Nazanin --text=../langdata_lstm/fas/fas.training_text
ERROR: Non-existent flag --max_pages=10
ERROR: Program text2image failed. Abort.
```

I've search this error but no success. the max_pages parameters is set correctly, but no reason for box files exist not to be created.
What is the error says and how to resolve it?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I faced the max_pages issue and solved it with copmpiling from source not using the released tar.